# Codeanywhere Environment

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, environment, codeanywhere

I'm Using CodeAnywhere as my IDE and I wanted to use testing Environment not development.

how can I do that?

when I try `Console.Log(process.env)`

this comes out

```
{ MANPATH: '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man',                               
  TERM: 'xterm-256color',                                                                                                                      
  SHELL: '/bin/bash',                                                                                                                          
  SSH_CLIENT: '(Confidential)',                                                                                                        
  NVM_PATH: '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node',                                                                                  
  OLDPWD: '/home/cabox/workspace',                                                                                                             
  SSH_TTY: '/dev/pts/0',                                                                                                                       
  NVM_DIR: '/home/cabox/.nvm',                                                                                                                 
  USER: 'cabox',                                                                                                                               
  LS_COLORS: 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:o
w=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;3
1:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.ja
r=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.g
if=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*
.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;
35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01
;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;
36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00
;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:',                                                                                                                
  MAIL: '/var/mail/cabox',                                                                                                                     
  PATH: '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/bin:/home/cabox/.npm-packages/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/
usr/games',                                                                                                                                    
  NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR: 'https://nodejs.org/dist',                                                                                            
  PWD: '/home/cabox/workspace/login-app',                                                                                                      
  SHLVL: '1',                                                                                                                                  
  HOME: '/home/cabox',                                                                                                                         
  LOGNAME: 'cabox',                                                                                                                            
  SSH_CONNECTION: '(Confidential)',                                                                                     
  NVM_BIN: '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/bin',                                                                                        
  LESSOPEN: '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s',                                                                                                          
  NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR: 'https://iojs.org/dist',                                                                                                
  LESSCLOSE: '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s',                                                                                                        
  _: '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/bin/node' }
```

I if I can add some variables into this environment, then how can I do that?

if I want to create another Environment, then how can I do that?

Comment: create .env file in root directory and use there key to set environment variable. for reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: you can simply add this in package.json file under scripts key `"test": "set NODE_ENV=test&&node server.js"` then start your server using `npm run test` command